# Definition of stable under isomorphism

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am reading a paper 'A coding of separable Banach spaces' and it says 'we identify a family of separable Banach spaces which is stable under isomorphism with a subset of $C=\{$closed subspaces of$ C[\triangle]\}$.
However, I have looked online for a while and haven't found a definition of what it actually means for a family to be stable under isomorphism. (the definition isn't in the paper)
Does anyone know what it means?
Thank you

Comment: It means that if $X$ belongs to the family of separable Banach spaces and and $Y$ is isomorphic to $X$, then $Y$ belongs to the family too. E.g., consider the class/family of all separable Banach spaces that are reflexive, or the class of all Banach spaces whose dual is norm separable.

Answer (score 0):

It means closed under isomorphism.